# Как сделать так, чтобы бот в телеграмме на Aiogram писал сообщение пользователю по буквам как ChatGPT?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, chatgpt

У меня есть бот в телеграмме, он работает, но отправляет сообщение после того, как сервер OpenAI отдаст ответ в `response`.

Я бы хотел, чтобы сообщение отправлялось как у ChatGPT, по буквам, постепенно генерировалось на глазах у пользователя.

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_messages(message: types.Message):
    global user_message
    global voicer_text
    global text
    global photo_text
    global user_is_replying
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Карсон печатает . . .")
    await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=user_id, action=types.ChatActions.TYPING)    
    try:

        if user_id in user_is_replying and user_is_replying[user_id]:
            await message.answer("Подождите, Карсон немного перегружен.")
            return


        if photo_text == True:
            user_message = message.text + "\n" + text
            
        elif voicer_text == True:
            user_message = text
            
        else:
            user_message = message.text
        # Проверяем длину сообщения пользователя
        if len(user_message) > max_allowed_message_length:
            await message.reply("Извините, ваше сообщение слишком большое, и я не могу на него ответить.")
            photo_text = False
            return

        if photo_text == True:
            update(user_id, 'user', message.text + "\n" + text)
            
        elif voicer_text == True:
            update(user_id, 'user', text)
            
        else:
            update(user_id, 'user', message.text)

        user_is_replying[user_id] = True
        #user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": f"Язык: ru"})
        
        response_content, response = await call_openai(message)
        #response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        if len(response_content) + len(user_message) >= 15500:
                    await message.reply("Слишком большой запрос . . .\nОшибка на сервере :(")
                    photo_text = False
                    return
        if response['usage']['total_tokens'] >= 15000:
            await message.reply(
                f'В данный момент вы использовали максимум токенов в рамках контекста: {response["usage"]["total_tokens"]}, будет произведена очистка памяти'
            )
            reset_messages(user_id)

        await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=user_id, action=types.ChatActions.TYPING)
        if voicer_text == True:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id + 2)
            await message.reply(response_content, parse_mode="markdown")
                        
        else:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id + 1)
            await message.reply(response_content, parse_mode="markdown")
                        
        photo_text = False
        voicer_text = False
        text = ""
    except aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantParseEntities as ex:
        await message.answer("Извините, произошла ошибка, пожалуйста, попробуйте повторить запрос.")
    except aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound as ex:
        await message.answer("Произошёл сбой, повторите запрос")
    except openai.error.InvalidRequestError as ex:
        await message.answer(error_2)
        photo_text = False
    except openai.error.RateLimitError as ex:
        await message.answer(error)
        photo_text = False
    finally:
        user_is_replying[user_id] = False
    return False


    
# Функция для асинхронного вызова OpenAI
async def call_openai(message) -> str:
    global user_message
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    # Или какой-то другой способ получения сообщения от пользователя
    user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})
    openai.aiosession.set(ClientSession())
    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=user_messages[user_id],
        temperature=0.8,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0.3,
        max_tokens=max_token_count,
    )

    response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    await openai.aiosession.get().close()
    return response_content, response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш код:

```
message=await message.reply("Загрузка...")
str=''
for i in message.text:
    str_=str_+i
    await message.edit_text(str_)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Не уверен в правильности именно *названий* функций, написал скорее алгоритм